# PHPUnit: Mock a method to behave like identity

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

Using PHPUnit, is there any way to mock a method and make it **behave like identity** (x->x) ? Something around the lines of :

```
$this->myMethod(Argument::any())->willReturn(<should return the argument untouched>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `returnArgument()`  method. From the doc:

> Sometimes you want to return one of the arguments of a method call
>   (unchanged) as the result of a stubbed method call. Example 9.4 shows
>   how you can achieve this using `returnArgument()` instead of
>   `returnValue()`.

As Example:

```
class StubTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testReturnArgumentStub()
    {
        // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
        $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')
                     ->getMock();

        // Configure the stub.
        $stub->method('doSomething')
             ->will($this->returnArgument(0));

        // $stub->doSomething('foo') returns 'foo'
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stub->doSomething('foo'));

        // $stub->doSomething('bar') returns 'bar'
        $this->assertEquals('bar', $stub->doSomething('bar'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that already, but it seems the returned argument isn't of the same object class, but of class PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_ReturnArgument. So I can't call any method on the returned object. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @MarcPe-Pe can you provide some code of your test? A minimal scenario is appreciated

Comment: Thank you for your help @Matteo. I refactored my Service by creating a sub-Service, easier to test. I guess facing the sort of problem I was having can outline a design issue in one's code. I'll mark your answer as accepted as it is also the closest I had come to answer that specific question.

Comment: Hi @MarcPe-Pe you are welcome! I agree with you about the testing practice can help on improve the design!